# error configuring log4j-nosql

Tags: java, mongodb, log4j, log4j2

I'm trying to set up log4j-nosql, but I'm consistently getting the following error:

```
ERROR appenders contains an invalid element or attribute "NoSql"
```

My log4j.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="trace">
  <properties>
  </properties>
  <appenders>
    <NoSql name="mongo">
      <MongoDb databaseName="xxxx" collectionName="log" server="localhost"
               writeConcernConstant="UNACKNOWLEDGED" />
    </NoSql>
  </appenders>
  <loggers>
    <root level="warn">
      <appender-ref ref="mongo"/>
    </root>
  </loggers>
</configuration>
```

My POM contains the following aritifacts related to log4j:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-nosql</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${mongo-driver.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I've tried versions 2.2 and 2.3 of log4j, and versions 2.11.3, 2.12.3, and 2.13.0 of the MongoDB driver.

The build succeeds, and my jar file executes properly.  But I am always getting the error that says "NoSql" isn't a valid appender (error quoted at the top of this question).  I'm run xmllint on my log4j.xml and found no errors.  I verified that I'm including the correct configuration file (e.g. it works if I specify a RollingFile appender).  I've unzipped my compiled jar and verified that it contains log4j-nosql.jar.  I'm at a loss for what to try next.  Can anybody help?

Comment: I've also found [this post](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-403), which addresses the issue with non-authenticated MongoDB connections.  I've updated my log4j version to 2.4 and also tried 2.5.  I also tried adding authentication, but upon checking my mongodb.log file, I've noticed that log4j is not even attempting a connection.  It appears that there is something wrong with my configuration, although I can't figure out what that might be.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug which occurs on some cases. check [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-691) they fixed it. maybe you need to update your jar

Comment: the fix in the post applies to changes in version 2.0-rc2, which changed the packaging to separate out the NoSql appender from the core to a separate jar, which is log4j-nosql.  I've already added that to my pom.xml, and I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue and solved it by adding following API:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

See the below XML I have used for NoSQL configuration with Log4J2 API, in a `log4j2.xml`:

```
<Appenders>
    <NoSql name="databaseAppender">
        <MongoDb databaseName="DB name" collectionName="collection name"
            server="localhost:27017" username="user name" password="DB password" />
    </NoSql>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="databaseAppender" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Reference: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/appenders.html#NoSQLAppender